# Split string by string in F#

Tags: f#

In C# I could go like

```
data.Split(new string[] { "splitHere" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I can't seem to get the same to work in F# or I may simply be doing it wrong (I just recently started to learn F#)

**Update**
Just to clarify, my best attempt was

```
data.Split([", "], StringSplitOptions.None)
```

I'm fairly new to F# and moved from C#, so I make a number of noob errors still.
On the up side, I couldn't find any info when searching for this subject, and now there's at least 1 :)

Comment: You can still call that method. What have you tried, and where are you having problems?

Comment: "... simply be doing it wrong."... It would help if you showed your attempt.

Comment: What I'd tried was amongst other things 
Split([", "], StringSplitOptions.None)

Which didn't work because I forgot the vertical separator lines, thanks both of you for replying :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split string by string like this:

```
open System
let colors = "red, green, blue"
let colorsArray = colors.Split([|", "|], StringSplitOptions.None)
```

and the result is

```
val colorsArray : string [] = [|"red"; "green"; "blue"|]
```

Comment: Derp, I forgot the vertical separator symbols, that's why it wasn't working. Thanks!